# Wordpress consolidate meta_query fields into list with unique values

Tags: metadata, wordpress

I'm trying to output a list from a extra field I've put into a custom post. Some of the posts contain the same value in this field so when outputting the list I'd like to remove the duplicates. Anyone know how to do this?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'client',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'AND', array(
        'key' => 'client',
        'compare' => '='
        )
    )
    );
    $query_clients = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I then drop this inside the loop to get the meta value out of each post

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'client', true);  
<li><?php echo $meta ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer. It's not pretty but it works just by checking each meta data item against the previous one. Obviously this will only work if I have them in alphabetical order.

```
<?php if ($query_clients->have_posts()): while ($query_clients->have_posts()): $query_clients->the_post();
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'client', true); //get the post meta field out of each post 
if ($temp_name != $meta){
    $temp_name = $meta;
?>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo $meta ?></a></li>
<?php
}
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I hope this helps someone.